# Steady Flow of Data to SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to write a piece of software which collects signals from different bus systems (e.g. CAN Bus, Ethernet) and then saves the data in a data storage.

Another piece of software then uses the data in the database to operate.
So basically i need constant write access on the one side and constant read access on the other side.

I thought about using SQLite because i had good experience with it because its ease of use. But i also experienced problems with two processes simultaniously using the database file.

So my question is: Is SQLite still the right thing for a use case like this or are there alternatives? Like a whole SQL Server thingy? Or some completely other approach? I can't think of a practical one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look up [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to be it.